# Spinbox mouse click and arrows

Tags: tkinter, mouseevent, python-3.5, mousewheel

I am developing a sort of rolling button with the tkinter.Spinbox widget and I need to know how to address the Entry widget that the Spinbox is wrapping, in order to bind only the inner Entry widget to the mouse wheel and to the mouse left button, and leave the arrows behavior unchanged (up and down).
Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The spinbox doesn't wrap an entry widget, it's an independent widget.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Tcl/Tk lower level, but if you look at [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-June/003189.html), a ttk.Spinbox might be possible with just a few lines of code by just inheriting from tkinter.Entry, thus even if I don't understand how the tkinter.Spinbox is related to Tcl/Tk (see its __init__() method of just 1 line: "Widget.__init__(self, master, 'spinbox', cnf, kw)"), I would assume it should not be so much different from the possible ttk version...

Comment: Just a correction to the previous comment: "just inheriting from tkinter.Entry" should be instead "just inheriting from ttk.Entry".